Error initializing filters when trying to use arnndn
I’m trying to do noise reduction on an audio clip using the arnndn filter from ffmpeg:
ffmpeg -i audio.aac -af 'arnndn=m=mp.rnnn' audio_out.aac
but I keep getting the error
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5928550d3e80] Error initializing filters Error reinitializing filters! Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid data found when processing input
and I tried with different input files. Do I need special dependencies to use arnndn?
I’m using this ffmpeg version:
ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
configuration: --prefix=/home/ffmpeg-builder/release --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-libs=-lm --disable-doc --disable-debug --disable-shared --disable-ffprobe --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avfilter --enable-filters --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-cuvid --toolchain=hardened --disable-stripping --enable-opengl --pkgconfigdir=/home/ffmpeg-builder/release/lib/pkgconfig --extra-cflags='-I/home/ffmpeg-builder/release/include -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc ' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/ffmpeg-builder/release/lib -fstack-protector -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc ' --extra-cxxflags=' -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc ' --extra-libs='-ldl -lrt -lpthread' --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-gmp --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libshine --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --ld=g++ --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-openssl --enable-zlib --enable-nonfree --extra-libs=-lpthread --enable-pthreads --extra-libs=-lgomp
libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100

